# Angular late loading problem Optimization of images

Tags: angular, image, optimization, pagespeed

When I do the site speed test in my angular project, the performance is very low, the main.js file shows as the reason, what should I do about main js. Although I use the ng optimization feature of Angular, the images are loaded late, the lcp score is low, what should I do about it

Main.js file size is 680 KB I tried everything to reduce it but it doesn't work. The fcp and lcp performance value ​​on the page are negative.